# Troubleshooting a 401 Unauthorized error IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have a webapp which is a .NET 4, webforms app running on IIS 7.5 on Server 2008.  Recently and apparently sporadically users trying to use the app on a mac are being presented with an error page stating:

401 Unauthorized - Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
You do not have the permission to view this directory using the credentials that you supplied.

The page doesn't provide any further information or substatus codes.  I have checked the IIS error logs for more information and have found that this issue does seem to be unique to users on a mac most commonly Safari but it does also happen on other browsers such as Firefox.  Again no substatus code is provided in these logs.

The error message provided seems to be consistent with a 401.1 however I am using forms authentication and not windows authentication.  I have been unable to reproduce this myself and at the moment it apparently happens at random for users and not consistently after a set of specific steps.

This error occurs when users are in the app or trying to log in, I do not think it is related to them entering invalid credentials as I have validation to handle that and it can happen to users already logged into the app.

As I can't reproduce the error I am not sure how to approach solving this problem, I would like some guidance to this regard and any solutions or ideas that you guys can come up with.  If more information is needed let me know and I can update the question.

EDIT:

I had an idea that maybe some configuration on a mac was causing a WWW-Authenticate header to be sent when it isn't required, but after using TamerData to add the header I found I still couldn't replicate the issue.  All authentication in IIS is disabled with the exception of anonymous and forms.

EDIT 2:

I have now been able to successfully reproduce the issue, it occurs when an unauthenticated user attempts to access a protected page with a ?ReturnUrl=value parameter.  This will cause IIS to display the error page described above.  I can fix this behaviour by removing the ReturnUrl parameter on any unauthenticated attempts to access a protected page and redirect the user to the login page in Begin_Request.

However this issue has been reported most commonly on a page which is redirected to immediately **after** a user has just logged in.  So for some reason the user is still being sent a 401 error when they are in fact authenticated.  Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Is it possible to do with Safari and its tracking block mechanism?  
Google are in trouble for circumventing it.  
http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/economy/faq-what-privacy-settings-was-google-flouting-and-why-does-it-matter/2012/02/17/gIQADTE5JR_story.html

Comment: I am reading that link now, but I do have occurrences of this problem on browsers other than Safari.

Comment: Another possiblity is that the users or server time/date is incorrect. I've seen it in when the date is incorrect and the session cookie/header fails. Are there any users that you know who are failing?

Comment: I tried making the requests with a mismatched datetime on the client to the server and wasn't able to replicate, but I have been able to reproduce the issue now but I still don't understand why it is triggered in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to see what the header information is when it fails?

Comment: Unfortunately whilst I can directly cause the error myself I cannot get the conditions for which our users are experiencing the problem and therefore cannot see their header information.

Comment: that be in your server logs my friend